# Foursquare Venues outdated data?

Tags: foursquare

The last days I spent trying around with the Foursquare Places API. 
When I send a normal "search" query for venues:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=48.03468,14.2091&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&v=20181010&radius=8000&categoryId=<a bunch of categories>
```

Then I often get duplicated venues (same restaurant for instance just another name for it) or venues which are not existing anymore.

Is this normal or is the reason for this that I use the "Sandbox" Account and not a bought one (like StartUp).

Another question: 
The 'Opening Hours' query (/venue/id/hours) does not provide opening hours. Same reason, or is there just no data available in the Foursquare Database?